# Financial proof to get a Schengen visa to France

Tags: schengen, paperwork, proof-of-funds

I am planning to apply for a Schengen visa to visit France. I have an *attestation d'acceuil*, but the visa requires I submit bank statement for the past 3 months. I can get this statement, but the problem is that my company has been paying my salary in cash for the past months, and I place the money into the account by myself.

Can I submit the following?

- my accounting book (current account)
- letter from the bank stating that I have money in it
- payslips for the past 3 months

Will that satisfy the financial requirements for the visa?

Comment: I believe it would, but it might be more sensible to get a verified bank statement from the bank instead of your accounting book. It will show the monthly credit in your account which you do in order to deposit your salary.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply reply so it is better to submit all documemts(letter from bank,saving book,payslips)in addition to the bank statment. Is it ok?

Comment: I'm no authority on the matter, but yes that's what I'd do. :)

Comment: Read this answer: http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/27650 it tells all you need to know about bank statements for visa applications.

Answer (score 2):

I submitted exactly those things earlier when I got my Schengen sometime ago (except for the paystubs, even though I had a part time job as a student in my university) and the documents were accepted as complete.